# Show a Google Calendar frame in a django template

Tags: python, html, django-templates, google-calendar-api

What i want to do is to create a google calendar with many events (i already know how to do it) and show this calendar in a frame inside a template. On the internet i've found some informations about it, but it seems i need to manage every calendar i create manually. For every calendar i have to click on "three dots/options" and make it visible and share it on my code. I don't want to do these operations, i only need a frame connected to the existing google calendar that show me the events.

Thanks in advance!